# Emulate filtering-by-property in Django, using property and queryset annotation

Tags: python, django, properties, django-queryset

### Summary

It appears we can create a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) on a Django model, *and* add an [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with the *exact same name* to querysets for that model.

For example, our `FooBarModel` has `foo = property(...)`, and on top of that we can do `FooBarModel.objects.annotate(foo=...)`.

Note that the names are the same: If `foo` were a normal attribute, instead of a `property`, `annotate(foo=...)` would raise a `ValueError`. In this case, no such error.

Initial tests suggest this approach works, allowing us to create e.g. a quasi filterable-property.

What I would like to know: Is this a good approach, or could it lead to conflicts or unexpected surprises of some sort?

### Background

We have an existing database with a `FooBarModel` with field `bar`, which is used in many places in our project code, mostly to filter `FooBarModel` querysets.

Now, for some reason, we need to add a new field, `foo` to our model, which should be used instead of the `bar` field. The `bar` field still serves a purpose, so we need to keep that as well. If `foo` has not been set (e.g. for existing database entries), we fall back to `bar`.

*This has to work both on new (unsaved) model instances and on querysets.*

Note: Although a simple [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) would be an alternative solution for the specific example provided below (fallback), there are more complicated scenarios in which data migration is not an option.

### Implementation

Now, to make this work, we implement the model with a `foo` `property`, a `_foo` model field, a `set_foo` method and a `get_foo` method that provides the fallback logic (returns `bar` if `_foo` has not been set).

However, as far as I know, a `property` cannot be used in a queryset filter, because `foo` is not an actual database field (`_foo` *is*, but that does not have the fallback logic). The following SO questions seem to support this: [Filter by property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1205375), [Django empty field fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342679), [Do properties work on django model fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1454727), [Django models and python properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11014138), [Cannot resolve keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18447798)

Thus, we add a customized manager which annotates the initial queryset using the [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) class. This duplicates the fallback logic from `get_foo` (except for empty strings) on the database level and can be used for filtering.

The final result is presented below (tested in Python 2.7/3.6 and Django 1.9/2.0):

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # add a `foo` annotation (with fallback) to the initial queryset
        return super(FooManager,self).get_queryset().annotate(foo=Coalesce('_foo', 'bar'))


class FooBarModel(models.Model):
    objects = FooManager()  # use the extended manager with 'foo' annotation
    _foo = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)  # null=True for Coalesce
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='something', blank=True)

    def get_foo(self):
        # fallback logic
        if self._foo:
            return self._foo
        else:
            return self.bar

    def set_foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

    foo = property(fget=get_foo, fset=set_foo, doc='foo with fallback to bar')
```

Now we can use the `foo` property on new (unsaved) `FooBarModel` instances, e.g. `FooBarModel(bar='some old value').foo`, and we can filter `FooBarModel` querysets using `foo` as well, e.g. `FooBarModel.objects.filter(foo='what I'm looking for')`.

Note: Unfortunately the latter does not appear to work when filtering on [related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7489635), e.g. `SomeRelatedModel.objects.filter(foobar__foo='what I'm looking for')`, because the [manager is not used](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#base-managers) in that case.

A drawback of this approach is that the "fallback" logic from `get_foo` needs to be duplicated in the custom manager (in the form of `Coalesce`).

I suppose it would also be possible to apply this "property+annotation" pattern to more complicated `property` logic, using Django's [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) in the annotation part.

### The Question

The approach above emulates a filterable model property. However, the annotation named `foo` shadows the `property` named `foo`, and I am not sure if this will lead to conflicts or other surprises at some point. Does anyone know?

If we add a "normal" annotation to a queryset, i.e. one that does *not* match a property name, such as `z`, that `z` shows up as an attribute (when I call `vars()` on an instance from that queryset). However, if we use `vars()` on an instance from our `FooBarModel.objects`, it shows *no* attribute named `foo`. Does this mean that the `get_foo` method overrides the annotation?

Comment: Tried this question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), but it is considered off-topic there because it contains example code.

Comment: "However, if we use vars() on an instance from our FooBarModel.objects, it shows no attribute named foo." Have you tried implementing `foo` as a property using the `property` decorator followed by the `foo.setter` decorator, as opposed to having three distinct names (`foo`, `get_foo`, `set_foo`)?